# On hover, add active state to div, then check if div is active, then if active, add other active state to separate div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a series of parent `div`s with the first of those parents having a default active state on load.
The active class is removed and added to other parent divs when they're hovered.
However, I'd also like my function to add a separate active class state to another `div` (technically a `child div`) when the `parent div` has its active class.
First `child div` also has an active state on load.
I am using jQuery and not CSS for this because I also have `third div` shown when hovered over its corresponding parent, hence `hov1`, `hov2`, etc.
Plus I want the default active states on load.

Here is my jQuery:

```js
$('.parent').hover(function() {
    $('.active-parent').removeClass('active-parent');
    $(this).addClass('active-parent');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active-parent')) {
        $('.arrow-right').addClass('arrow-right-hov')
    }
    else {
        $('.arrow-right').removeClass('arrow-right-hov')
    }
}),
```

Here is the HTML:

```html
<h1 class="parent active-parent hov1">
    Cybersecurity
    <div class="arrow-right arrow-right-hov"></div>
</h1>
<h1 class="parent hov2">
    High-Performance Computing
    <div class="arrow-right"></div>
</h1>
<h1 class="parent hov3">
    High-Frequency Trading
    <div class="arrow-right"></div>
</h1>
```

I would greatly appreciate any help - thank you!

**EDIT:**

This is the javascript that ended up working. No more `if` statements.
Initial `arrow-right-hov` and `active-parent` default states are removed when hovering on another div with the same `parent` class.
`arrow-right-hov` is added when the `active-parent` class is present.
Active states remain on mouseout.

```
$('.parent').hover(function() {
    $('.active-parent').removeClass('active-parent');
    //remove default parent active state when hovering another parent

    $(this).addClass('active-parent');
    //add active parent state on hovered div, remain active

    $('.arrow-right-hov').removeClass('arrow-right-hov')
    //remove default secondary active child class on parent hover

    $(this).children(".arrow-right").addClass('arrow-right-hov');
    //add active child class on active parent
}),
```

Thank you to [ikiK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7158959/ikik) for getting me in the right direction!

Comment: Instead of JS, why don't you use CSS and the `:hover` pseudo?

Answer (score 1):

Is this effect you where after?

If so, you do not need if statement;

```
    $(this).addClass('active-parent');
//on this line you have added the class too hovered H1
    if ($(this).hasClass('active-parent')) {
// so this right after will always be true
```

And you can simply target

```
$(this).children(".arrow-right")
```

to apply it to children with class `.arrow-right`

let me know if i got something wrong, to adjust it.

```js
$('.parent').hover(function() {
  $('.active-parent').removeClass('active-parent');
  $('.arrow-right').removeClass('arrow-right-hov');
//first remove from all on any parent hover
    $(this).addClass('active-parent');
    $(this).children(".arrow-right").addClass('arrow-right-hov');
//then add only to hoverd

})
```

```css
.active-parent {
  color: red
}

.arrow-right-hov {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="parent active-parent hov1">
  Cybersecurity
  <div class="arrow-right arrow-right-hov">arrow-right</div>
</h1>
<h1 class="parent hov2">
  High-Performance Computing
  <div class="arrow-right">arrow-right</div>
</h1>
<h1 class="parent hov3">
  High-Frequency Trading
  <div class="arrow-right">arrow-right</div>
</h1>
```

Welcome to SO

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! This is quite close, and almost got it. I added just a line or two extra and it worked!

Comment: @EmilyJaynes Well seeing now your edit, its the same thing, if the HTML markup is the same in production as its in question ;)  Anyway glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes JS is not needed. CSS and the `:hover` pseudo can achieve the same result:

```css
/* STYLE ACTIVE and HOVER */
.parent.active-parent,
.parent:hover {
  color: HOTPINK;
}

/* STYLE ACTIVE and HOVER arrows */
.parent.active-parent .arrow-right,
.parent:hover .arrow-right{
  color: DEEPPINK;
}

.arrow-right:after {content: "\279c";}
```

```html
<h1 class="parent active-parent hov1">
  Cybersecurity
  <span class="arrow-right"></span>
</h1>
<h1 class="parent hov2">
  High-Performance Computing
  <span class="arrow-right"></span>
</h1>
<h1 class="parent hov3">
  High-Frequency Trading
  <span class="arrow-right"></span>
</h1>
```

If you want you could even target a parent element and override styles when tha tcommon parent has the state `:hover`